# When does Torah attribute birth to the mother and when to the father?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers

I spot two approaches to informing a birth in the Torah:

1. **attributing it to the mother**, for example: "... הִנֵּה **יָלְדָה מִלְכָּה גַם־הִוא בָּנִים** לְנָחוֹר אָחִיךָ׃", “Milcah too has borne children to your brother Nahor":
2. **attributing to the father**, for example: "וְאֵלֶּה תּוֹלְדֹת תֶּרַח **תֶּרַח הוֹלִיד אֶת־אַבְרָם** אֶת־נָחוֹר וְאֶת־הָרָן וְהָרָן הוֹלִיד אֶת־לוֹט׃", "Now this is the line of Terah: Terah begot Abram, Nahor, and Haran; and Haran begot Lot."

Is there a general rule?

Please provide sources.

Comment: It says elsewhere that girls to father and boys to mother https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8:%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%AA_%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8

Comment: Maybe by terach since it doesnt mention the mother and they were not the same mother they are attibuted to the father.

Comment: @interested I suspected that each case could be learned in place. I asked if there is a general rule applied.